# Error while compiling android 3.10 kernel source

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, toolchain, android-kernel

Recently I tryed to crosscompile android kernel for my xiaomi mi4c.
To do this I have downloaded and configured toolchain like this:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9 -b  marshmallow-release toolchain64
export ARCH=arm64
export SUBARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=`pwd`/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
```

then I cloned kernel source from here: https://github.com/AndropaX/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8992

and do this:

```
make clean && make mrproper
make ARCH=arm64 resurrection_libra_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=$CROSS_COMPILE -j3
```

Then I have an error:

```
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:14:0,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:15,
                 from /home/owner/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8992/arch/arm64/include/asm/compat.h:25,
                 from /home/owner/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8992/arch/arm64/include/asm/stat.h:23,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:5,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.c:26:
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI_ISA1000.c: In function 'ImmVibeSPI_ForceOut_SetSamples':
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:64:16: error: implicit declaration of function 'KBUILD_STR' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  static struct _ddebug  __aligned(8)   \
                ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:76:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:240:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI_ISA1000.c:573:2: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
  pr_debug("%s: level = %d\n", __func__, level);
  ^
<command-line>:0:27: error: 'tspdrv' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:66:14: note: in expansion of macro 'KBUILD_MODNAME'
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:76:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:240:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI_ISA1000.c:573:2: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
  pr_debug("%s: level = %d\n", __func__, level);
  ^
<command-line>:0:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:66:14: note: in expansion of macro 'KBUILD_MODNAME'
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:76:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:240:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI_ISA1000.c:573:2: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
  pr_debug("%s: level = %d\n", __func__, level);
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.c: At top level:
drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.c:94:37: fatal error: tspdrvOutputDataHandler.c: No such file or directory
 #include <tspdrvOutputDataHandler.c>
                                     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
compilation terminated.
```

So, the question is, what am I doing wrong? Maybe I need another toolchain for crosscompilation? Can sombody suggest one? I dont think there is an error in the kernel code. So what can go wrong?

Comment: It may not make a difference, but your shell input is unconventional.  (1) Since you exported the ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE env variables, you don't have to specify them again in the **make** command. (2) CROSS_COMPILE is meant to be just the command prefix, and not the entire path.  Modify the env variable PATH to include your toolchain. (3) A `make mrproper` causes the previous `make clean` to be superfluous.  (4) Try a build without the `-j3` option.  IIRC there have been occasional issues with parallel jobs.

Comment: This looks like the same issue: https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

So, after a few days I found the answer. Thanks to kay2777 from 4pda.

Look for KBUILD_CFLAGS in the main Makefile, and add the following to suppress warnings as errors:

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -w
// if all errors are to be suppressed

KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable
// if that specific error is to be suppressed.
```